# finding different element in column numpy

Tags: python, numpy

i am using numpy to find different element in the first column of numpy array i am using below code i also look at np.unique method but i couldn't find proper function

```
k = 0
c = 0
nonrep=[]
for i in range(len(xin)):
    for j in range(len(nonrep)):
        if(xin[i,0]==nonrep[j]):
         c = c+1
    if(c==0):
     nonrep.append(xin[i,0])
    c=0
```

i am sure i can do it better and faster using numpy library, i will be glad if you help me to find better and faster way to do this

Comment: Do you need to maintain order? If not, use : `np.unique(xin[:,0])`.

Comment: @Divakar thanks alot for your help. it works.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not the good way to do it. Since here you perform membership checks by performing linear search. Furthermore you do not even `break` after you have found the element. This makes it an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm.

## Using numpy *O(n log n)*, no order

You can simply use:

```
np.unique(xin[:,0])
```

This will work in *O(n log n)*. This is still not the most efficient approach.

## Using pandas *O(n)*, order

If you really need fast computations, you can better use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(xin[:,0])[0].unique()
```

This works in *O(n)* (given the elements can be efficiently hashed) and furthermore preserves order. Here the result is again a numpy array.

Like @B.M. says in their comment, you can prevent constructing a 1-column dataframe, and construct a sequence instead:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(xin[:,0]).unique()
```

Comment: @B.M.: yes! thanks for your comment. I included it in the answer.